# Nextjs application with basePath 404 error with apache reverse proxy

Tags: reactjs, apache, next.js

I am using an apache reverse proxy with a custom basePath. The application runs on `http://localhost:300/abc`, that's what I use in my apache config for both ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse. My application runs completely fine on the localhost, but it does not work when trying to open the url that the application is supposed to run on. I get a 404 error for the `_next` folder, which looks like this:

```
GET https://my_url.com/abc 404 (Not Found)
abc:1 GET https://my_url.com/abc/_next/static/chunks/main-3c1ab6de33e375184ee7.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
abc:1 GET https://my_url.com/abc/_next/static/fCdfRYDyffxB73K0CRH3c/_buildManifest.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
abc:1 GET https://my_url.com/abc/_next/static/fCdfRYDyffxB73K0CRH3c/_ssgManifest.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

When I remove the `basePath` parameter from my `next.config.js`, I do not get these errors but that however breaks my api calls.

My abc.conf:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass /abc http://localhost:3000/abc
ProxyPassReverse /abc http://localhost:3000/abc
[...]
```

**EDIT**:
Adding `app.use('/_next', express.static('_next'))` removes the last 3 errors, but the first one prevails.

Comment: I was able to get rid of the last 3 errors by adding `app.use('/_next', express.static('_next'))`. However, the first error still prevails, hence there must be a problem serving some other files.

Comment: Did you get this fixed?  I'm getting this issue too.

Comment: @Steven Edison did you try the edit? I think my error was, that I didn't restart apache properly so the changes didn't take effect. I will check my settings again and get back to you if I notice something!